# Fused Location Provider Stops With No Reason

Tags: android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm Using **Fused location provider** to get frequent location updates based on the users need. Using **BroadCast Reciever** to recieve the location updates with the **LocationRequest** Class.

Using pending intent I'm initializing the reciever.

```
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, mIntentService, 0);
```

And getting the Location updates from fusion provider.

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, mPendingIntent);
```

All these are going well for certain period of time. After some time say for 2 hours or more then suddenly the **BroadCast Reciever** is not recieving any updates and its so unusual that there is no reason why it got stopped.

I haven't stopped the application or Stopped recieving the location update from the **FusedLocationApi**

Comment: Did you look at the logcat? Is there anything interesting in there? Also, is this only on Marshmallow or also older apis?

Comment: [This SO issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279773/fusedlocationapi-background-location-service-stops-receiving-updates-randomly) might be related to your inquiry.

Comment: @Shmuel Not specified to any versions, its common. Nothing special in the logcat

Comment: @adjuremods There is no accepted answer in it any how i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

> I think Nothing wrong in your `FusedLocationApi`. The problem is
>   `BroadcastReceiver`.

A process that is currently executing a `BroadcastReceiver` (that is, currently running the code in its `onReceive(Context, Intent)` method) is considered to be a foreground process and will be kept running by the system except under cases of extreme memory pressure.

Once you return from `onReceive()`, the `BroadcastReceiver` is no longer active.

This means that for longer-running operations you will often use a **`Service`** in conjunction with a **`BroadcastReceiver`** to keep the containing process active for the entire time of your operation.

For more [click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: I use an IntentService and the issue also happens to me